# React Router Dom isn't rendering my pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to learn react, but I am stuck with react render dom which doesn't want to render my page.

My App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route exact path='/' component={ HomePage }/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my *index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` do you have installed? From the project directory please run `npm list react-router-dom` and report back. I ask because you are using the v5 `Route` component API and there are a lot of outdated tutorials out there still referencing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Router v6 doesn't support exact anymore because all paths are match exactly by default. And **component** changes to **element** in v6. You need also to import **Routes** from react-router-dom.
Finaly, HomePage must be `<HomePage/>`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './pages/homepage/homepage.component.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={ <HomePage/> }/>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is two answers now where you've incorrectly claimed that RRDv6 `Route` components don't support the `exact` prop. This isn't entirely true. It's not a prop used by the `Route` component, but in React extraneous props are generally just ignored. They won't be the cause of any rendering issues like making a route not work.

Comment: If you were using TypeScript you would have quickly realized that Exact is no longer supported in v6 since your code would not compile with exact on Route.

I invite you to see the Route types on the React Router GitHub

Comment: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx

Comment: That's Typescript, and OP isn't using TS. React won't care if extra props are passed, it won't break anything. The `exact` prop isn't an issue.